# Calendario semanal pero sin horas con React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

estoy intentado crear una interfaz de usuario como la de la imagen, donde pueda guardar mis clases y todo lo que hago en ellas de manera rapida y sencilla.
Estoy buscando un componente que me ayude a hacer esto o crear uno propio con react.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Explico un poco que es lo que necesito:

- Que se muestre una tabla (de lunes a viernes) con los diferentes eventos (que serian las clases con sus asignaturas)
- Que pueda expandir el evento para ver su contenido
- No quiero que se muestren las horas tipo un calendario, porqué cada asignatura necesito que tenga un tamaño distinto, en función de su contenido.

Conoceis algun componente que me pueda ayudar a hacer todo esto que necesito?
Actualmente el backend ya lo tengo creado, con sus endpoints y todo; donde se guardan cada uno de los eventos (o asignaturas) con su fecha y hora.

Espero que podais ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución a lo que necesitas es la librería FullCalendar la cual se [puede integrar con el marco React](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react).

Personalmente e utilizado está librería cada vez que necesito mostrar calendarios y eventos en mis páginas. Además, la documentación provee varios [ejemplos](https://fullcalendar.io/demos) útiles. Espero te funcione!

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, el problema es que algo tipo eso me limita a que aparezca si o si la hora, o que la posicion de cada evento esté directamente relacionado con la hora, y yo lo que necesito es flexibilidad en este aspecto, que pueda poner mis eventos a mi antojo (en cuanto a tamaño de altura) y que simplemente se tenga en cuenta la posicion arriba o abajo segun la hora, no el tamaño. Es dificil de explicar, por eso la imagen